# Directory.GetFiles always appending application folder even with given path

Tags: c#

I'm trying to search for all the *.bak files in the user's desktop. I'm using this to search for them.

```
string[] fNames = new DirectoryInfo(@"%homepath%\Desktop")
                     .GetFiles("*.bak")
                     .Select(x => x.Name)
                     .ToArray();
```

my path is `@"%homepath%\Desktop"` (user's desktop)

While debugging, I'm getting an `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException`, checking the path, I've noticed this:

[image: I know it's in Spanish, but it's pretty self-explanatory]

As you can see, it's trying to append the given path (`@"%homepath%\Desktop"`) to the path where the application is being ran from.

I've tried all sorts of different path formatting and always the same.

Comment: You say "which is a relative path" - where do you think it is relative to?

Comment: %homepath% is *not* a relative path.  You simply forgot to expand the variable, it is not automatic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, `%HOMEPATH%` is not (always) where your user profile is located - e.g. if your Home Folder is redirected by AD then it will be that instead, and if the redirection is to a different drive, you will need `%HOMEDRIVE%`.

If you want to locate the desktop folder and you are on Windows, you should use

```
var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

So your code should be:

```
string[] fNames = new DirectoryInfo(desktopPath)
                     .GetFiles("*.bak")
                     .Select(x => x.Name)
                     .ToArray();
```